# Evap coil port position does not match cover knockouts

Tags: hvac, evaporative-cooling

I need to replace the evap coil on my Lennox CBX27UH-036, which is a brand I regret buying because of the poor quality of their parts (there was a class action lawsuit exactly for what happened to my evap coil). I found [this](https://www.acwholesalers.com/Goodman-CAUFA3526C6/p114291.html) matching dimensions and tonnage but the three ports are positioned differently than on the original.

I cannot talk with Lennox because they won't talk with customers, only their "registered techs", which is IMO a dishonest business practice of forcing to use the company for service after buying their product (John Deere recently agreed not to do this anymore). So I am on my own, the tech I brought in (who is obviously not Lennox) told me to buy the part and he would install it. Which means I have to find the correct part.

My question is, if the position of ports on the aftermarket coil does not match the knockouts on the OEM cover, does that mean it cannot be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position of the connections is not very important. Covers are just sheet metal; we have tools for making new holes and closing old holes! It isn't even required to use the OEM cover; a substitute can be fashioned from a piece of sheet metal. However, it's preferable to choose a coil that has its refrigerant connections arranged such that your existing line set can be bent and re-positioned to work with the new coil. Otherwise one will have to extend the line set by brazing on a short section of new copper tube. (Perfectly do-able, but as a tech it's nice to avoid the extra work, avoid creating one more potential leak, etc.)

Matching the dimensions of the coil isn't terribly important either -- it's convenient if they match, but mismatched physical size can be overcome with sheet metal.

In choosing a new coil somebody needs to ensure that the associated refrigerant metering device is compatible with your existing condenser/compressor. In the case of Goodman like the one you linked, in the photo one can see the small liquid line connection has a nut with a clear plastic window. Behind these there's a small brass piston with a teflon seal. A new Goodman condenser includes a piston, seal, and a 3/8" tube elbow fitting packaged with it. I use the nut from the coil (discard the piston, seal, and plastic window) together with the piston, seal, and elbow from the condenser.

By the sound of it you're keeping your existing condenser. In that case you'd need to determine whether it will work properly with a fixed orifice/piston, which size to use, acquire that if it's different to the one included with the coil, and find a source for the elbow or other means to attach on that liquid port.

On the other hand, if your existing condenser is designed to work with a TXV then I can't help you -- I haven't installed any of those!

Comment: yes, keeping the same condenser

Comment: the problem is that no technician wants to find the part for me -- i am on my own. and i am not completely sure how to check compatibility

Comment: my condenser is `Lennox XC14-036-230-06` -- do you think it is compatible with the Goodman coil ?

Comment: @amphibient I found a Lennox manual for that part. It's contradictory: on page 19 it says either fixed orifice or expansion valve is fine, but on page 26 it says not approved for fixed orifice. It looks like the connection is the same either way, though, so probably the tech can remove the orifice or TXV from your current coil and transfer it to the new one. If yours has an orifice, note the Lennox manual indicates the orifice would have been included with the condenser, so do like I do with all-Goodman systems: discard the orifice that arrives in the new coil and re-use the old one.

Comment: so basically, use the old orifice with the Goodman ? is that correct ?

Comment: I actually made a new question how to find a matching coil: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/272227/how-to-find-compatible-evap-coil-for-hvac-system