# How to find compatible evap coil for HVAC system?

Tags: hvac

I have a Lennox system, air handler `CBX27UH-036` and condenser `XC14-036-230`. After the cooling stopped working (but both inside and outside fans and compressor work), a technician told me it was 99% the coil that has a leak because it is a [known issue with Lennox products](https://www.hoffmannbros.com/nashville/lennox/evaporator-coil-replacement). He told me to find a coil replacement and he would put it in but he wouldn't do the searching for the part.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a database online that matches models with parts, like there are with vehicles so he told me to find one that matches the dimensions and tonnage, which [I did](https://www.acwholesalers.com/Goodman-CAUFA3526C6/p114291.html). Are there any other criteria that needs to be matched (like the type of refrigerant regulator AKA TXV)?

Answer (score 4):

Be sure it will mechanically fit into the place the old coil is or understand some mods will have to be made. There are different mechanical dimension (Flat, A frame etc) for coils of the same capacity. You have chosen an A frame, the mounting and clearance needs to be checked.

How did the technician determine there was a leak or is this just an assumption?

I am not there so this is just a SWAG.If it is an assumption I would have the technician check it with a leak detector. The plenum chamber could be closed off as much as reasonable possible and after setting for while with at least a partial charge check where the leak is on the coil. Many times it may be fixable and a lot of $$$ less expensive then a replacement.

Comment: just an assumption based on the system being flat and that being a known issue with Lennox -- I decided not to do a $150 nitrogen test

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with full Model number

Confirm it is CBX27UH-036-230-1

The OEM coil for that model is Genuine OEM Part # 34M33 RC Item # 2346032

Found here :[coil](https://www.repairclinic.com/PartDetail/Evaporator/34M33/2346032) and other places.

Search therm : Lennox 34M33 INDOOR COIL

It will cost you $$2,201.73 in parts only. The labor is extensive and only qualified HVAC can do it, since it involves refilling the coolant.

Comment: hence the aftermarket part

Comment: Not being picky but this not an answer. The OP already has already found the coil and is asking for additional criteria to match it to fit his unit. The OP already has an installer. Shopping and pricing are frowned upon on this site.